# Why do I need to "bundle install" before pushing a rails app to heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundler

I suppose the bundling is going to happen on the heroku servers anyway. What is the purpose of doing it on the local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bundle install
```

This ensures that all gems specified in Gemfile, together with their dependencies, are available for your application. Running bundle install also generates a Gemfile.lock file, which should be added to your git repository. Gemfile.lock ensures that your deployed versions of gems on Heroku match the version installed locally on your development machine.

> If the platforms section of your Gemfile contains Windows entries,
>   such as mswin or mingw, then the Gemfile.lock file will be ignored.

Heroku also uses that file to resolve and install your application dependencies automatically. All you need to do is to push it.

Refer this link : [Click Here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler)

Answer (score 1):

This will update your `Gemfile.lock`, that heroku uses to install all your gems on your virtual server. The `Gemfile.lock` contains all information about your gems and their respective versions.

Comment: Can't heroku figure out that information just from my Gemfile? Does bundling it on my system provide additional information?

Comment: @spartacus: `Gemfile.lock` specifies exact versions of used gems. The last thing you want is to have heroku introduce a bug by installing a different version from the one you use locally.

Answer (score 1):

It has two purposes :

1. It ensures you that, on your machine, you have all the dependencies for your application satisfied;
2. It updates the `Gemfile.lock` file. While the `Gemfile` has the list of your app's gems, the `Gemfile.lock` has a more.. "detailed" version of it, with the gem's own dependencies, their version constraints... It basically is a snapshot of your project dependencies. This way, your app in production will run with the exact same versions of third-party code as do your code in local.

Answer (score 0):

This ensures that all gems specified in Gemfile, together with their dependencies, are available for your application. Running bundle install also generates a Gemfile.lock file, **which should be added to your git repository. Gemfile.lock ensures that your deployed versions of gems on Heroku match the version installed locally on your development machine.**

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler